# Why are there 4 separate bytecodes for executing static/virtual/interface/special methods when one would suffice?

Tags: java, bytecode, javac

Since each method call includes the target method signature it seems to me that the class verifying step could tell by analysing the target whether its invoking a static, virtual etc and do the right thing ?

Is having 4 byte codes a waste of 3 byte codes or is this merely self documenting if one dumps a class file using javap ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about `invokeinterface`, `invokespecial`, `invokestatic`, and `invokevirtual`, there *are* differences between them. The effects on the stack for a start.

Comment: Everyone knows that at runtime different schemantics occur. My observation is that the runtime can figure out using the signature and meta data of the target method and from that do the right thing. If anything, encoding the type of the target is redundant as this information can be gathered from the actual source. After examining the target, the invokeinterface code path would be used for interfaces, invoke virtual for method interfaces and so on.

Comment: @mP: "Figuring out" what to do, it seems to me, is largely a compile-time activity. We don't want to slow down the interpreter by making it do work the compiler can do, unless there's a very good reason (e.g., platform independence).

Comment: But the verifier also checks if the method-invoke matches the method type of the target - just as it verifies visibility, types it also checks the method <-> invoke instructions match...Try it if you want. All the meta data javac uses to parse, verify and emit byte code is also present at runtime. The runtime knows the method types, visibility, type etc all that is encoded in class files.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have only invoke opcode for both virtual and static. Let's assume in compile time you have

```
Test {
        public static void test(Test t) {
        // static method
    }
}
```

and somewhere a call to this static with pseudo bytecode

```
push t
jmp Test.test(T)V
```

Now let's assume someone uses another Test class in runtime

```
Test {
    public void test(Test t) {
        // obj call
    }
}
```

In this case `jmp Test.test(T)V` is still valid. The problem is that it will mess up the stack. Two different opcodes allow to catch this problem link time.

Comment: There are better ways to format your code, please click the [orange question mark](http://i.imgur.com/GjKAG.png) in the question or answer text box for an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The class verifier checks if you have the wrong invoke code. The runtime does not check each time it invokes a method to see if the target is compatible with the original invoke type. Imagine if it did things would unbarelable slow and its also unnecessary. Do the check when the class is loaded and since there is no practical way to redefine methods short of hacking memory your code can execute knowing the target is compatible with teh callsite.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been possible. However, it would add extra cost every time one of the instructions is interpreted. So performance would be harmed for very little advantage.

It has been argued that separate instructions improve security, by reducing the chances of confusing the VM. Not sure I'm convinced by that.

Comment: The VM is never confused as it always validates and complains if code has a invoke virtual when the target is now an interface(needing a invoke interface). This can of course happen if you update a third party jar and the target changes from an interface <-> class etc.

Comment: @mP The argument is that combining the instructions would increase the risk of a vulnerability.

Comment: What vulnerability ? The runtime when loading a class knows the target it does verify the instruction matches the target. If the method invoke ins is wrong for the target yourll get a verification load error

Comment: @mP Potential vulnerabilities. They happen.

Comment: Impossible. All type information available to the compiler (method type(static/virtual/interface), visibility, return type, parameter etc) are available at runtime. The meta data required to deducate the target method is available for the runtime to check and ddo the right thing. If your going to say *vulnerabilities* you need to demonstrate a real example. Your comments are plain wrong.

Comment: @mP You are saying that vulnerabilities are impossible? Even for Stack Overflow, that doesn't strike me as particularly smart.

Answer (score 0):

you need this opcodes because at the time the bytecode references for methods are laid out, they only contain symbolic references to entries in the constant pool. To resolve these references, you need to know on which type you need to resolve: for example, the difference between invokespecial and invokevirtual is static vs dynamic binding . For invokespecial you resolve on the type of the reference, not the class of the object. This information cannot be gleaned without the compiler putting in a special opcode to distinguish the methods. In java the code is typically linked dynamically, which is what forces these opcodes.

Answer (score 0):

At least `invokespecial` is needed to be a separate instruction since java allows explicitly calling the super implementation of an overridden method:

```
class Super {
    public void m() { }
}
class Sub {
    public void m() {
        super.m();
    }
}
```

The call in `Sub` has to be an `invokespecial` since it would otherwise just call itself and run out of stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think This debate was unnneccesary as java have this design decision. Not sure but you might want to look at one more What they call user defined data endpoints : [invokedynamic](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/scripting-jvm-languages/invokedynamic-101.html)